# CMake only build lib when compiler supports C++20 or higher

Tags: c++, cmake

in our project we are using the highest available C and CXX standard by setting

```
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

However the project is also build with some old compilers that do not support C++20.

Some libs on the other hand require C++20. How can i configure my project so that these libs are only build if the compiler supports C++20?
(I know i could use `#ifdef __cplusplus >= ...` but I'm trying to avoid `#ifdefs` ;))

Thx for your help
:)

Comment: From your comment below one of the answers, your question is formulated misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the variable name speaks for itself. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED.html

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)
```

You should prefer `set_target_properties`.

> My expectation is that old compilers automatically skip building the c++20 lib

So do not add target if we don't have C++20.

```
if(NOT "cxx_std_20" IN_LIST CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES)
   add_library(the_lib_to_skip ...)
endif()
```

Comment: yeah but I still want to compile the project with old compilers as well (just omitting the new lib) If I set it to required, the project will not be buildable with old compilers right?

Comment: I do not understand, what do you expect. So don't set it to required, if you don't want it to be required.

Comment: I want to be able to build my project with new and old compilers. The c++20 lib is only needed for a few targets. My expectation is that old compilers automatically skip building the c++20 lib

Comment: `old compilers automatically skip building the c++20 lib` So _check_ if your compiler has C++20 and disable those targets. This is different to  enforcing.

Comment: and how can I check the supported language?

Answer (score 3):

CMakeLists of libraries should only specify usage requirements.

For example if your library requires at least C++11 standard at build time & consume time:

```cmake
target_compile_features(mylib PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
```

With this compile feature, by default CMake takes care to inject proper compilation flags so that this target is compiled with a C++ standard greater or equal than C++11 (it depends on compiler and its version).

Do not hardcode `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` in CMakeLists of a library, because it prevents users to compile with a different compatible C++ standard (and it's not uncommon to want to compile all libraries of a dependency graph with the same C++ standard).

Then if you want to build this lib with a very specific standard, you can inject `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` externally during CMake configuration:

```
cmake -S <source_dir> -B <build_dir> -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=20
```

=============================================

And now that you have clarified your question:

```cmake
add_library(mylib1 ...)

# only build lib2 if compiler supports C++20 standard
if("cxx_std_20" IN_LIST CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES)
    add_library(mylib2 ...)
    target_compile_features(mylib2 PUBLIC cxx_std_20)
endif()
```

I would suggest to display a summary at the end of your configuration, because it can be quite surprising for users to silently disable the build of several libs.